# Eclipse CDT Builtin Include Directories

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

Under

```
Eclipse CDT >
    Project Settings > 
        C/C++ General >
            Paths and Symbols >
                 Includes >
                     GNU C++
```

There is a list of include paths.

Some are in bold and are project specific.

Others are **builtin**:

For example:

```
 /usr/include/C++/4.6/
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 etc
```

If I delete:

```
work/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/*.sc
```

The paths are automatically rescanned when Eclipse launches.

I have gcc 4.6 and gcc 4.7 installed side-by-side.

**When Eclipse rescans it only finds the 4.6 headers and not the 4.7 ones.**

My question is this:  By what mechanism does Eclipse determine the list of builtin include paths?  (and hence why is it only finding the 4.6 headers and not the 4.7 headers?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is controlled by the settings on Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Discovery Options.  By default, Eclipse will call g++ to discover the include directories.  The first instance of g++ on the path will be the one that gets invoked.  You can always set the full path to the compiler you want it to use for your project.

Comment: Discovery Options are hidden by default, and can be enabled from Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Property Pages Settings > Display "Discovery Options" page.