# cpp files run correctly, but editor is broken

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

The code on a sample project looks like this:

[image]

errors include:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved
```

however, running the project successfully outputs:

```
!!!Hello World!!!
```

I guess the auto completion portion of it is not looking at the correct files, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It might be that eclipse is not looking in the right place for the libraries, you need to see where to set that up

Comment: try rebuild index? right click over project and look for rebuild index.

Comment: going to check out this suggestion tonight, thanks

Comment: rebuilding the index didn't do anything, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instructions by languitar fixed my problem:

[Eclipse Juno with CDT Doesn't Add Built-in Include Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259616/eclipse-juno-with-cdt-doesnt-add-built-in-include-directories)

hes says,

> Please
>
> ```
> Open the Eclipse Preferences dialog (Windows | Preferences).
> Open C++ | Build | Settings.
> Open the Discovery tab.
> Select the built-in compiler settings entry.
> Press the Clear Entries button.
> ```
>
> Afterwards eclipse should request the defaults again from the
>   compiler.
>
> On Arch Linux I had to do this after each GCC version change, because
>   in that case the locations for the defaults changed as the version is
>   encoded in the folder name, and eclipse does not notice this.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply need to rebuild your index, but otherwise you just need to set up the IDE "discovery" options.

I can't tell you how to do that without knowing what Eclipse you have, what toolchain, and all the other unknowns. Clearly your compiler *does* know where these things are, and that's the important thing.

Anyway, if you look in your project properties, under "C/C++ General", you should find the relevant options in "Preprocessor Includes" and/or "Paths and Symbols".

In particular, "Preprocessor Includes" -> "Entries" -> "C" should list the locations it thinks are right. If they're not, try fiddling with the "Providers" and find some settings that do give the right locations. You may have to run a build for some providers to detect the locations.

Comment: i think you're onto something, C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.->GNU C++->CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings is empty. however, the under the same Entries menuf or GNU C, CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings has a drop down that has entries like /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6include, /usr/local/include, among many others.